# Not able to find subnodes in HP Quality Center after level 2

Tags: vba, excel, qtp, hp-quality-center

I am working on VBA to fetch subfolders from Quality Center. I am able to fetch folders under Subject but not able to fetch subfolders. 
Error I am getting is : Object Required

```
Set Treemgr = QCConnection.TreeManager

On Error GoTo ErrCatcher
   Set TestFolderNode = Treemgr.NodeByPath("Subject\Divisional Release") '

ErrCatcher:
     If Err.Number Then

     End If
```

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/To-get-the-subfolder-list-from-QC-using-OTA/td-p/4789857) can help you. It is not exactly the same issue as yours (poster is getting different error here) but the syntax and logic used might help you out. I'd also advise you to check the [OTA documentation](http://jawedm.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/download-qc-ota-api-reference-handbook.html) for further assistance

Comment: Actually, I've found an online version of the OTA Documentation [here](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/webframe.html). It contains many useful examples that could help you. If you look into `Code Samples\Requirements Examples\Find a specified requirement in a specified folder`, you will see a logic to walk down a tree